# DynamoDB SCAN operation cost with "Limit" parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm pretty new to AWS DynamoDB and having read the documentation I'm not 100% sure what happens to cost calculations when using the '**Limit**' parameter in a **SCAN** operation.

I understand that one should design the tables so that **QUERY** operations are predominantly used and that a **SCAN** will scan the entire table, thus consuming a lot of read capacity. I also understand that a FilterExpression doesn't affect that cost of scanning the entire table, but filters what is returned *after* the entire scan, and if the total number of scanned items exceeds the maximum data set size limit of 1 MB, the scan stops and results are returned.

What I'm not sure of, is whether the '**Limit**' parameter is a type of FilterExpression, or whether it stops an entire scan, thus reducing read costs.

For example, if I had an activity table with a sort key that is a date field (updatedAt) and it had a million rows. If I performed a SCAN with a Limit = 10 (in order to get the very latest 10 activities), I would obviously get back 10 rows but would I be charged for reading a million rows? Cost is my main concern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `Limit` will also rediuce the consumed read capacity, here is the relevant part from the [DynamoDB docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScanGuidelines.html):

> The Scan operation provides a Limit parameter that you can use to set the page size for your request. Each Scan or Query request that has a smaller page size uses fewer read operations and creates a "pause" between each request. For example, if each item is 4 KB and you set the page size to 40 items, then a Query request would consume only 40 strongly consistent read operations or 20 eventually consistent read operations. A larger number of smaller Scan or Query operations would allow your other critical requests to succeed without throttling.

As you can see **each Scan or Query request that has a smaller page size uses fewer read operations**.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This does answer the question, though I've recently realised that a Scan's order is random right now rather than maintaining the order of the sort key. This means I was not able to get the latest 10 activities via an updatedAt field. Thanks for confirming cost question.

Comment: @elprl but if the `updatedAt` field is your sort key, why do you use `scan` operation and not `query`?

Comment: In my particular case the table's hash key was a hashTag string and the sort key was an updatedAt epoc number. ["#cat": 1462812033, "#dog": 1462812073, ...]. Hence, why I needed the ''scan'' to get all the hashtags since time X.

Comment: @elprl it this case you can probably use the global secondary index to make another index with different hash / range keys and then use query on this index

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions Boris. In the end, I did use a GSI with a hash key as updatedAtPeriod (a reference to a particular day) and the sort key set to the updatedAt field again. This essentially bucketed activities to a particular day. It felt like a workaround, whereas a scan with a Limit seemed more elegant at the time.